# ¿Cómo puedo colocar la siguiente línea para que se configure desde el arranque dentro de /etc/fstab o en /etc/rc.local en ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

La linea que quiero implementar es:

```
ssh -fNv -L 3049:localhost:2049 ubuntu@20.115.5.61
```

Ahorita la coloqué dentro de /etc/rc.local como:

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_host=ubuntu@20.115.5.61
remote_port=3049
local_port=2049
cmd="ssh -fN -R ${remote_port}:localhost:${local_port} ${remote_host}"

while true; do
    pgrep -fx "$cmd" >/dev/null 2>&1 || $cmd
    sleep 10
done
```

Pero si lo hago manual me pide contraseña y con éste script no puedo ingresarle la contraseña.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: no sé añadiste reglas en el firewall para la conexión y configurar el demonio para excepción de superusuario?

Comment: Se me ocurre que dentro del bash te metas como superusuario y metas la contraseña. Para ello puedes hacer `echo "sudo su"`, `sleep 1`, `echo "{TU CONTRASEÑA}"`. Ya te digo, es un poco chapuza, pero por probar...